# What bind operator will be used?

Tags: haskell, monads

Look at this example:

```
ReaderT Integer (ErrorT String (StateT Integer Identity)) Integer
```

What operator bind `(>>=)` will be used here ?
For example, if we use `do` notation, then what bind operator will be chosen by compiler ?

Comment: `ReaderT`s bind. You can look at the source to see what it does.

Comment: From what you know it ?

Comment: it's the outermost constructor. The outermost constructor controls it.

Comment: Is it rule ? Can we something similar about result of run* ?

Comment: what is "run*"? It's because of the way `>>=` in defined. Most things are defined that way.

Comment: Ok, I don't understan how to run such monad. Could you give more precisely answer, please ?

Comment: Something with an outer layer of ReaderT can be be "run" via [runReaderT](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-Reader.html#v:runReaderT).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For reference, `(>>=)` has the type

```
(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

and also note that

```
ReaderT Integer (ErrorT String (StateT Integer Identity)) Integer
```

is the same as

```
(ReaderT Integer (ErrorT String (StateT Integer Identity))) Integer
```

because type application (like function application) is left associative in Haskell.

So, given

```
x :: ReaderT Integer (ErrorT String (StateT Integer Identity)) Integer
```

and an `f` with the appropriate type, in the expression

```
x >>= f
```

the type checker will try to match the type of `x` with the left argument type of `(>>=)`. This means it will try to unify `ReaderT Integer (ErrorT String (StateT Integer Identity)) Integer` with `m a`. The only way that this unifies is by taking `a` to be `Integer` and `m` to be `ReaderT Integer (ErrorT String (StateT Integer Identity))`. So, using the `~` type equality notation, we end up with

```
 m ~ (ReaderT Integer (ErrorT String (StateT Integer Identity)))
 a ~ Integer
```

As a result, it must use the `(ReaderT r n)` instance of `Monad`, where `r ~ Integer` and `n ~ ErrorT String (StateT Integer Identity)`.

This is a result of how type unification works in Haskell in general, not just for `(>>=)`, so this general idea can be used for interpreting how the type checking of other polymorphic functions works.

Comment: so bind is chosen based on left argument of bind ?

Comment: @HaskellFun Not quite. If the return type of the right argument, here called `f`, didn't use the same Monad instance as the left argument the compiler would give a compiler error. Also, if the monad instance of the left argument is left polymorphic but the right argument uses a specific monad, it will match based on the right argument's monad.

Comment: With `x >>= f`, the compiler tries to match both `m a` against the type of `x` *and* `(a -> m b)` against the type of `f`.

Comment: hmm, assuming that none of cases that you mentioned above happened - then decision is based on left arguement ?

Comment: @HaskellFun It's really always based on *both* argument types, neither of them is more important than the other. If `x :: Maybe Int` and `f :: Int -> [Bool]`, then `x >>= f` won't type check even though both `Maybe` and `[]` are `Monad`s. The `m` can't unify to two different types.